# Usefulness of std::make_unique and std::make_shared in C++1z

Tags: c++, c++17

With C++17 we get template type deduction for class templates. So a lot of `make` functions could become obsolete.

How about `make_unique` and `make_shared` ?

So we can write

```
unique_ptr myPtr(new MyType());
// vs
auto myPtr = make_unique<MyType>();
```

so can we forget about those functions?

Comment: Have a read of Herb Sutter: https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/  Both `make_unique` and  `make_shared` are need to so as to provide Exception Safe Function Calls.

Comment: @RichardCritten : I'm pretty sure [P0145](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf)'s incorporation into C++17 nullifies that particular safety issue.

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you so much for the link to that paper.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Neither `unique_ptr` nor `shared_ptr` are constructible without explicitly providing the type, due to the inability to distinguish between `T*` and `T[]`. Writing `unique_ptr{new int}` is ill-formed.

Additionally, `std::make_shared` does more than just construct a `std::shared_ptr` for you without you having to type `new`. It also allocates both the object and the control structure in a single allocation, which saves you both an allocation and gives you locality for when you have to change the reference count.

Answer (score 9):

You forgot about one of the most important reasons we got `make_unique`. Consider the difference between these two function calls:

```
some_function(make_unique<T>(), std::vector<U>{1, 2, 3});
some_function(unique_ptr(new T()), std::vector<U>{1, 2, 3});
```

One of these functions has a subtle error in it. Can you guess what it is?

If the `vector` constructor throws, then something really bad can happen. Because of C++ function argument expression evaluation rules, it's possible that the order of evaluation can be `new T()` followed by `std::vector<U>{1, 2, 3}` followed by `unique_ptr<T>`'s constructor. If the `vector` throws, then the `new`ed pointer is never freed.

That's bad. And that's about 90% of the reason why we have `make_unique` at all.

Now having said that, C++17 *also* makes a change about the evaluation of function argument expressions that makes this point obsolete. C++17's rules guarantee that there can be no overlap *between* the different expressions that initialize arguments. That is, each argument's initializer expression completes in full before another one can begin. C++17 doesn't guarantee the order of the argument expressions, but there cannot be interleaving between subexpressions.

In the above code, the evaluation order may be `vector` first, or `new T()` first. But if it evaluates `new T()` first, it must evaluate `unique_ptr<T>()` before evaluating the `vector` constructor.

So in C++17, both of these are safe. So while template argument deduction does not obsolete `make_unique`, C++17 as a whole does.

Of course, there's always an issue of standard compliance. A compiler might implement constructor argument deduction *before* implementing expression evaluation ordering rules. And there's no way to make your code break if expression evaluation ordering isn't there (not unless you're relying on the feature test macros, which some compilers don't support).

So just to be safe, I'd suggest sticking with `make_unique` in such circumstances.

And lastly, there's the special feature of `make/allocate_shared`: the ability to allocate the control block and the object in the same storage. This is not an unimportant feature of `shared_ptr`, and it *cannot* be replicated with template `new`.

So you should keep using `make_shared` where possible.